# Update database with case when sets value to '0'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I observe a quite strange behaviour in mysql and would be very happy for some advise.

I want to update fields in a column from 1 to 4 and 6 to 9. For this I am using as a test

```
UPDATE `test` SET `id`= case when 'id'= 1 then 4 else 'id' end where id =1
```

However when I run the above in phpmyadmin the values are changed to the number 0 and not 4.

If I I run the same query without case when like

```
UPDATE `test` SET `id`= 4 WHERE `id` =1
```

it works fine.

When I run

```
UPDATE `test` SET `id`= 
case when 'id'= 1 then 4 
when 'id'= 6 then 9 

else 'id' end where id in (1,6)
```

it replaces the 1 and 6 to '0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a numeric value as id's usually are of `INT` type in mysql. You are wildly mixing backticks (```) and (`'`), so you are implicitly casting the string `'id'` to an int, which results in 0.

```
select CAST('foo' as UNSIGNED) ---> 0
```

So you might want to change the query to use backticks all the time

```
UPDATE `test` SET `id`= case when `id` = 1 then 4 else `id` end where `id` = 1
```

Comment: Thank you bambam. It is working now and I really was not aware of this

Comment: You're welcome. Always use backticks (or nothing at all) for column and table names @user3358102